# Double integration (correction)

Tags: calculus, integration

I need your help to verify my answer. This is an exercice who I have to make but the manual doesn't give the answer.

I need to calculate the charge : $\sigma(x,y)=x+y+x^2+y^2$ on the disc : $x^2+y^2 \le 4$. I suppose the more easiest way to do it is to use the polar coordinates.

So, I can substitue $x:=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y:=r\sin(\theta)$, who implies $x^2+y^2:=r^2\cos^2(\theta)+r^2\sin^2(\theta)=4$. And the charge function become : $\sigma(x,y)=r(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))+4$.

Now, I can calculate the double integral :
$$\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \int_{r=0}^{r=4} \sigma(x,y)r \: drd\theta = 32\pi$$

So, is this the right integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to write 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\Big[r\Big(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta)\Big)+r^{2}\Big]rdrd\theta.
$$

you radius is $r=2$ and you are integrating on $r\leq 2$.

Comment: Thanks you. What result did you have?

Comment: Is the result $8\pi$?